# Accidentally blocked my server from accessing Gmail account; how to undo?

Tags: gmail

Gmail asked me if I recognized an IP, I said I didn't, and it was blocked.

Turns out that IP was from a server of mine that uses a Gmail account. It has already used it in the past, I don't know why Gmail asked again.

Now it's blocked, how can I undo that?

Comment: You could try the unblock captcha https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: @JohnC Didn't work this time (it used to work)

Comment: @JohnC I was looking for that, thanks! Not sure exactly how I made it work though, I fixed a couple of things at the same time so I'm not sure what was causing this problem.

Comment: No worries, wasn't sure if that would work when you'd blocked something yourself.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper Have you solved it?