# Accidentally blocked my server from accessing gmail account, how to undo?

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accidentally blocked my server from accessing Gmail account; how to undo?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33555/accidentally-blocked-my-server-from-accessing-gmail-account-how-to-undo)

Gmail asked me if I recognized an IP, I said I didn't, and it was blocked.

Turns out that IP was from a server of mine that uses a gmail account. It has already used it in the past, I don't know why gmail asked again.

Now it's blocked, how can I undo that?

Comment: @Alex It's the same question, they moved it from other site

Comment: I know. You should not cross-post questions on different SE sites. I flagged it to be removed.